# Attendees Field on Event object is null in backend

Tags: fields, event, calendar, data-types

In my use case I would like to grab all event where a certain user has been added as an attendee for the event.

When I do get records in the flow and I actually get null value in the Attendees field although the user has been added to that field and is visible on the UI side.

[image]
[image]

Is there any way where I can grab the users in the Attendees field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is present on Event Relation object rather than Event itself.

You need to query on event relation object. For example as below

`SELECT ID from EVENT where ID in (select EventID from EventRelation where RelationID ='someuserId')`